# Custom jquery function not working in view : Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

In Laravel 5.6 , I'm trying to use a progressbar plugin, I've installed it using `npm install progressbar.js` & required it in my `app.js` file.

I have also defined my custom function - `generate_circle()` in my `app.js` file.

When I call my custom function `generate_circle()` in the view inside a script tag I get the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: generate_circle is not defined

in my console. The plugin files are loaded correctly because I can see the plugin code in the `app.js` file.so that is not the issue.

Can anybody help me with this?

This is how my app.js file look like

```
require('./bootstrap');
var ProgressBar = require('progressbar.js');
function generate_circle(){
    var circle = new ProgressBar.Circle('.box',{
        fill: 'black',
        duration: 5000,
        warnings: true,
        step: function(state, circle, attachment) {
            circle.path.setAttribute('stroke', state.color);
        },
    });
    alert(1);
    circle.animate(1);
}
```

And this is my view :

```
--- header and other stuff --- 
<script src="{{URL::asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
    <script>
        generate_circle();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you compiled using npm

Comment: @FarrukhAyyaz what do you mean ? did i do npm run production or dev? i'm watching for changes and if thats what u meant i did ,because i can already see the plugin related code in my app.js file

Comment: in your app.js try `window.generate_circle = function { //your code }`

Comment: @xanadev this worked thanks !! oh man I've been banging my head at this for sooo long.

Comment: @ShamseerAhammed you're welcome.